# How do I add a version number to a SvelteKit/Vite app?

Tags: javascript, build, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I'm trying to create a system in my SvelteKit app where it shows you info about the current app version (ideally a Git commit hash and description) on a certain page. I tried using [Vite's define feature](https://vitejs.dev/config/#define) to do this at build time but it doesn't seem to work. How do I add something like this?

Here's an example of what I tried to do:

Vite config in svelte.config.js

```js
vite: () => ({
    define: {
        '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify('testfornow')
    }
})
```

index.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    const version: string = __APP_VERSION__;
</script>

<p>Current App version: {version}</p>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I managed to make it work:

- Get the package.json data as explained in the SvelteKit FAQ, and load it as a constant in Vite config:

```js
// svelte.config.js

import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
 
const file = fileURLToPath(new URL('package.json', import.meta.url));
const json = readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
const pkg = JSON.parse(json);

const config = {
  kit: {
    // ...
    vite: {
      define: {
        '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify(pkg.version),
      }
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

- Use the variable in any svelte file:

```html
<h2>Version: {__APP_VERSION__}</h2>
```

Quite similar to your example, hope it helps!

#### EDIT: Be aware, config changed after [@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.359](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/releases/tag/%40sveltejs%2Fkit%401.0.0-next.359):

After a breaking change on @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.359, Vite config must be included in its own file:

```js
// vite.config.js

import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
 
const file = fileURLToPath(new URL('package.json', import.meta.url));
const json = readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
const pkg = JSON.parse(json);

const config = {
  define: {
    '__APP_VERSION__': JSON.stringify(pkg.version),
  }
  // ...
};
```

And the `config.kit.vite` prop must be removed from the `svelte.config.js` file.

Comment: This worked as far as compilation and usage goes, but do you know how to get typescript to stop reporting that "__APP_VERSION__ is not defined"?

Comment: Place the following comment above the line when the variable is used: <!-- svelte-ignore missing-declaration -->

Comment: @TomaszPlonka Yes, this is what I do too for now.

Comment: Hm, that didn't work for me for some reason. But you did point me in the right direction, so I instead assigned `__APP_VERSION__` to another component-local variable with `// @ts-ignore` above it, and that did the trick 

Comment: @DigitalNinja There's a note in the [define section](https://vitejs.dev/config/#define) of the vite config object documentation that suggests to "... add ... type declarations in the env.d.ts or vite-env.d.ts file to get type checks and Intellisense." e.g. `declare const __APP_VERSION__: string`

Comment: Note that the keys of `define` are replaced in the code directly with their value. If it has a string value and you try to assign it to a variable then you'll have to add quotes in your code as well, e.g. you can do `const value = "__APP_VERSION__"`, but not `const value = __APP_VERSION__` (as it will then look for variable in the local scope with a name matching the value you defined).

Comment: For completeness, for vanilla Svelte it's {window.__APP_VERSION__}

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the [version](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#version) property.

File: **svelte.config.js**

```
const config = {
    ...
    kit: {
        ...
        version: {
            name: process.env.npm_package_version
        }
    }
}
```

With this you are tying the versions of the app and the package.json file.

And to use it:

```
import { version, dev } from '$app/environment';
...
console.log(`Client version: ${version}`);
```

Keep in mind that with this solution, if you update your app without changing the package.json version, inconsistencies can happen (check the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#version)).

Comment: perfect for me, and with minimum extra code

Comment: As of Dec 2023 this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 6):

(Updated answer) In my `vite.config.js` I use exec to obtain information from Git. Then I use Vite config option [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) to do constant replacements.

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process'
import { promisify } from 'util'

// Get current tag/commit and last commit date from git
const pexec = promisify(exec)
let [version, lastmod] = (
  await Promise.allSettled([
    pexec('git describe --tags || git rev-parse --short HEAD'),
    pexec('git log -1 --format=%cd --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"'),
  ])
).map(v => JSON.stringify(v.value?.stdout.trim()))

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
  define: {
    __VERSION__: version,
    __LASTMOD__: lastmod,
  },
  ...
```

If you use Typescript, this needs to go to `app.d.ts`

```js
// App version
declare const __VERSION__: string
// Date of last commit
declare const __LASTMOD__: string
```

Constants `__VERSION__` and `__LASTMOD__` are now available to the whole app. The only drawback is that vite-plugin-svelte complains they're not defined if you use them directly in the markup.

```html
<script context="module" lang="ts">
   const versionInfo = `Version ${__VERSION__}, ${__LASTMOD__}`
</script>

<div>{versionInfo}</div>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how to actually use `__VERSION__` inside a Svelte component? As it stands, your answer is only halfway there.