# How to display a package.json version in the footer of the site?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I would like to display a version that is declared in the package.json file in the footer of my site

How can I do this?

I found [this](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#read-package-json) FAQ explanation in their documentation, but unfortunately I don't know to access it from my component

```js
// svelte.config.js

import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
 
const file = fileURLToPath(new URL('package.json', import.meta.url));
const json = readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
const pkg = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `vite.define` to do this:

```js
const config = {
  kit: {
    vite: {
      define: {
        VERSION: pkg
      }
    }
  }
};
```

and in your component:

```html
<script>
  const version = VERSION;
</script>

<span>{version}</span>
```

**edit on 06.07.2023**

Seems the setup has changed in the time since the answer.
Now you can do this in `vite.config.js` as below:

```js
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const file = fileURLToPath(new URL('package.json', import.meta.url));
const json = readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
const pkg = JSON.parse(json);

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    define: {
        PKG: pkg
    }
});
```

and use

```html
<p>{PKG.version}</p>
```

Comment: how do you import `VERSION` and avoid `VERSION is not defined` error messages?  (using SvelteKit)

Comment: Just a nit, but I think it should be `VERSION: JSON.stringify(pkg.version)`, thanks.

Comment: @NickJonas With Typescript, you can add `declare const VERSION: string` to your `src/app.d.ts` to fix errors and warnings. [Vite Docs: Define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define).

Comment: Answer is outdated: "Unexpected option config.kit.vite"

Comment: @NatoBoram Updated for the latest version

Comment: Note that the keys of `define` are replaced in the code directly with their value. If you assign it a string value (instead of a JSON object as in the answer), then you'll have to add quotes in your code as well, e.g. `define: { SOME_VALUE: "test" }` could be used in your code as `const value = "SOME_VALUE"` (but not as `const value = SOME_VALUE` - unless `test` is a valid variable in the local scope).

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the party, but here's how I was able to achieve an answer to OP's question as of (14 Apr 23).

As per the [sveltekit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#read-package-json).

```js
// add the following to > svelte.config.js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const file = fileURLToPath(new URL('package.json', import.meta.url));
const json = readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
const pkg = JSON.parse(json);
```

As well as;

```js
// add the following to kit: {}
version: {
  name: pkg.version
}
```

Then in your desired component;

```html
<script>
  import { version } from '$app/environment';
</script>

<span>The package.json version is: {version}</span>
```

If you're planning to go the Vite route, you should read, urb_'s answer to a similar question asked here on S.O. [How do I add a version number to a SvelteKit/Vite app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034450/how-do-i-add-a-version-number-to-a-sveltekit-vite-app).

but in summary;

> **Be aware**, config changed after @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.359: After a
> breaking change on @sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.359, Vite config must be
> included in its own file:

Comment: Be careful with replacing `kit.version.name` as it is [used by SvelteKit](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/kit/src/exports/public.d.ts#L607) for HMR/change detection during development.
Also, the full warning linked seems to suggest to prefer using `vite.config.js` over `svelte.config.js`.